# count days between two dates not working correctly

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have slicer date in report. I use the following expression in order to calculate the number of days between two selcted dates

```
Remaining Days = 
VAR a =
    FIRSTDATE (MyTimeView[CC_DT_DATE])
VAR b =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( MyTimeView[CC_DT_DATE] ); ALLSELECTED (MyTimeView[CC_DT_DATE]) )
RETURN
    DATEDIFF ( a;b; DAY )
```

When I select 01/01/2020 to 31/01/2020, I am expecting to get 31 days but I get 29 days.

How to modify the expression,?

Answer (score 0):

[DATESBETWEEN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/datesbetween-function-dax) should work.

Something like:

```
Remaining Days =
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(MyTimeView),
    DATESBETWEEN(
        MyTimeView[CC_DT_DATE],  
        MIN(MyTimeView[CC_DT_DATE]),  
        MAX(MyTimeView[CC_DT_DATE])  
    )
)
```